# Does Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Support Android Emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, android-emulator

I am aiming to use an Android emulator with Android version 8 or higher. I've downloaded MS Visual Studio Emulator for Android (from Microsoft downloads) and installed it. Sadly the Android version in MS Visual Studio Emulator for Android was slightly outdated and none of them had Google Play Store.

Microsoft offers another solution, which is using the 'Android Emulator' (It's different from MS Visual Studio Emulator for Android) that potentially has a more recent Android version along with Play Store. In the setup documentation, it instructs me to select 'Android' from the Tools menu of Visual Studio and then followed by a set of other steps. However, my Visual Studio does not have the Android menu item under the Tools menu.

**Attempts made**: Here's the list of attempts I've made so far to get Android menu item under the Tools menu:

1. Installed Mobile development with .Net
2. Installed all the Individual Components related to 'Android' and 'Emulator' (Two emulators).
3. Turned Windows feature ON --> Hyper-V
4. Turned Windows feature ON --> Windows Hypervisor Platform

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 - Enterprise and Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. FYI: I also have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on the same computer.

**Question**: I was wondering, is it possible that I have no Android in the Tools menu potentially due to my Visual Studio being Community Edition?

**Edit**: After uninstalling Mobile Development with .NET workload and reinstall the same workload in VS2019 CE, once a project with the Android platform is opened, I am able to see the Android menu item under Tools menu. That will also confirm that Visual Studio Community Edition supports Android Emulator.